# How do I disable the Apple ID sign in when logging into my Mac?

Tags: macos, apple-id, login

Whenever I restart my Mac, I'm first required to sign in with my Apple ID and after that the Mac (local) account and password. It's sort of a two-step process and I don't remember where I may have accidentally configured this setting, which is really annoying right now.

How do I turn off the Apple ID sign in, so I'm only required to log into to my MacBook using my local user account?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this to disassociate your Apple ID password from login:

---

### To Stop Using an iCloud Password to Login to a Mac:

- Go to the  Menu and choose **System Preferences** (alternatively use LaunchPad or Spotlight to search for **System Preferences**
- Choose **Users & Groups** and select the primary Mac login that you want to disassociate the iCloud password and for which you wish to use a unique separate password
- Click the **Change Password...** button next to the user name
- At the prompt "Do you want to change your iCloud password, or stop using your iCloud password to unlock this Mac and create a separate password?" – choose "Use Separate Password…"
- Set and confirm the new password and close out of System Preferences when finished

Now when the user is logging into macOS, a separate account password will be used rather than the iCloud and Apple ID account password. This setting is specific to individual user accounts.

Source and further reading: [OSX Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/05/23/stop-using-icloud-password-mac-login/)